# How to call Wcf Service from javascript using vb.net code?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, wcf

How to call Wcf Service from javascript in vb.net ?I am getting error "Service call failed: 415 Unsupported Media Type".

My WebService code:

```
<ServiceContract()> 
Public Class Service <OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", 
BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _ 
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal Count As String) As String
Return String.Format("Welcome in WCF call")
End Function 
End Class
```

My  HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>Call WCF</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function CallMyService() {
            // debugger;
            //alert("hi");
            counter++;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:25057/WCFVB/Service.svc/MyFunction",
                data: '{"Count": "' + counter + '"}',
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
//                contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
                success: ServiceSucceeded,
                error: ServiceFailed
            });
        }

        // ---- WCF Service call backs -------------------

        function ServiceFailed(result) {
            //debugger;
            Log('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '  ' + result.statusText);
        }

        function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
            // debugger;
            var resultObject = result.MyFunctionResult;
            Log("Success: " + resultObject);
        }


        function Log(msg) {
            $("#logdiv").append(msg + "<br />");
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Execute" onclick="CallMyService();" />

    <div id="logdiv"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes.I am going to write here.

Comment: ok, it's getting clearer... how does your endpoint config looks like? Have you tested it with a GET-Function? Does the Webservice works by calling a GET over url? Service and html-site are both on the same server? The HTML is not running local?

Comment: While using GET function its showing "Service call failed: 400 Bad Request"

Comment: do you run your html on the same server like the service?

Comment: yes Service and html-site are both on the same server but diff URL.Is my code is right or not?

Comment: no i run the html page locally on client side.

Comment: looks fine, but I don't know your endpoint config. seems to be a configuration issue. if you are not running into same origin policy and you can not call the GET Functions over the Browser direct, your config must be broken. Please show your xml-config file. 
Where do they run? Locally: c:\yourhtml.html? have a look at [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: is this what u r asking for?endpoint address="http://localhost:25057/WCFVB/Service.svc

Comment: There is a xml file usually called App.Config. What is in there? See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec) tutorial for a good example of a wcf-rest service with json.

Comment: Why not call the WCF service using .NET?

Comment: SOAP is what we used ... we wrap everything in XML for encryption reasons and to add flexibility to the request and response values. Having said that, you can do virtually the same thing using a more REST-ful approach leaving the SOAP out of it. If you us soap, both the client and host need to use the same XML template. With REST, the request includes parameters 1-n and the response reacts accordingly.

Comment: Actually I dnt have any knowledge in .NET.can you plz give some example code or any links on this?Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of a little JavaScript request that runs against our WCF service - it's just a simple ping function in this case, but all the parts are there:

__*_*__*_*___ *edit* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

```
 <html> 
 <head>     
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" /> 
 <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>     
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function Ping() {             
   //set up varable
   var sContent;
    // 'Content-Type: text/xml \r\n ' +
    // 'Host: localhost:8085 \r\n \r\n  ';
    var s;
    s+="<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    s+="<s:Body><HostConnect xmlns=\"http://SomeURL \">";
    s+="<inMsg xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ \"      xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    s+="<a:TextSection>" ;
s+="&lt;Method value=\"ping\" &gt;";
s+="</a:TextSection>";
s+="</inMsg>";
s+="</HostConnect>";
s+="</s:Body>";
s+="</s:Envelope>";


   var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open('POST', Demo.URL.value, true);  
   //xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); /* ... */ 

 // alert(Demo.URL.value);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4||xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
        //alert("Ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString());
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("good");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Response: " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    if (xmlhttp.status !=200){
        //alert("bad");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Error: " +xmlhttp.status.toString() +"  response text:  " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
     } else {
       //alert("readystate bad");
     }
}
           xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST http:servername:8085/HostInterface/HostConnect HTTP/1.1"); 
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("VsDebuggerCausalityData","uIAA"); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","\"http://ServerName\""); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host","localhost:8085"); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Expect","100-continue"); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","639");                   
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
     xmlhttp.send(sContent);                  
  } 
 </script> 
  </head> 
  <body>     
  <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">         
  <div>
  Web Service URL 
  <input id="URL" type="text" size="140" value="" /><br />             
  <input type="button" value="Ping" onclick="Ping();" /><br />
  <textarea id="pingresponse"cols="100" rows="10"></textarea> <br />     
   </div>     
  </form> 
  </body> 
  <html>
```

Try this:

Comment: is it calling from HTML page or aspx ?I want calling from HTML page.

Comment: This is calling from an HTML page. I have a click event on a "Ping" button that executes this script.

Comment: What is the reference u have added to call this web service from HTML page?Can u post the Html page code?